# Replace a pattern in a column in R

Tags: r, data-mining

I want to delete the ":00" in the column 'female_male_ratio'.

[image: dataset]

Is there any code suggestions on how to do that ?

Comment: just do `sub(':00$', '', dat$female_male_ration)`

Comment: @Onyambu i did tht but when i print the dataset it does not change

Comment: Because you have to store it back into the dataset. ie `dat$female_male_ratio <- sub(':00$', '', dat$female_male_ration)`

Answer (score 1):

We can accomplish this by using `mutate` from the `dplyr` package and `str_remove` from the `stringr` package with the `regular expression` `":00$"` to ensure it's a `:00` prior to the end of the string and not in the middle like in `46:00:55`. Note, I am only using the `female_male_ratio` variable since you did not provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
  female_male_ratio = c("33: 67",
                       "42:58:00",
                       "46:54:00",
                       NA,
                       "37 : 63",
                       "45:55:00",
                       "46:54:00")
)


df_remove <- df %>%
  mutate(
    female_male_ratio = str_remove(female_male_ratio, ":00$")
  )

# A tibble: 7 x 1
   female_male_ratio
   <chr>            
 1 33: 67           
 2 42:58            
 3 46:54            
 4 NA             
 5 37 : 63          
 6 45:55            
 7 46:54
```

If you want to get rid of the `whitespace` in just the `female_male_ratio` variable, you can use `sub` from `base` R.

```
df_remove$female_male_ratio <- sub("\\s+", "", df_remove$female_male_ratio)


# A tibble: 7 x 1
  female_male_ratio
  <chr>            
1 33:67            
2 42:58            
3 46:54            
4 NA               
5 37:63            
6 45:55            
7 46:54
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>